# GetCurrentHwProfile not working in my "CLR Empty Project (.NET Framework)"

Tags: c++, .net, guid

I would like to make a Windows Desktop application that is checking the hardware ID of currently used PC.
I'm using VS2019 and created a "CLR Empty Project (.NET Framework)". I created a new C++ file with exemplary code available on learn.microsoft:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void main(void) 
{
   HW_PROFILE_INFO   HwProfInfo;
   if (!GetCurrentHwProfile(&HwProfInfo)) 
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("GetCurrentHwProfile failed with error %lx\n"), 
                 GetLastError());
      return;
   }
   _tprintf(TEXT("DockInfo = %d\n"), HwProfInfo.dwDockInfo);
   _tprintf(TEXT("Profile Guid = %s\n"), HwProfInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
   _tprintf(TEXT("Friendly Name = %s\n"), HwProfInfo.szHwProfileName);
}
```

Then I get the problems in this image: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlXkA.png)
When I do the same with an "Empty C++ Project" everything works as expected.

I would be really happy if someone could explain what's the problem and how to solve this.
Thanks!

Andy

Comment: If you read [the `GetCurrentHwProfile` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrenthwprofilea) it will tell you that you need to link with the `Advapi32` library. This library is usually not linked by default.

Comment: Please post error messages as text from the compiler output window, not screenshots of the error list